# C# Equivalent of command line assoc *.__ = ___

Tags: c#, console, file-association

I am trying to use my coding program in C# to associate files like *.geoclass or *.meowva so that they are, in explorer, called "Geoclass Code File."

Note: I do not need it to open with my application, all I need is the equivalent of this in the cmd.exe:

```
ASSOC .geoclass = Geoclass Code File
```

Comment: You could run that with the Process.Start method...

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358137/how-to-properly-add-file-associations-to-the-windows-registry) might be helpful. It explains the registry keys that are needed to do a file association

Comment: File associations for C# programs work just like for any other program. Windows (the component that tracks and implements file-association behaviors) doesn't care what language the program was written in. So first you need to research how to specify file associations in Windows. Then work from there to come up with an implementation specifically in C#.