# how to force that any file of a certain type will open with my program?

Tags: c#, winforms, file-format

i have build program that can open *.sdf files and show all the table & the data.

how to force that any *.sdf file in my computer will open with my program ?

thank's in advance

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-the-current-executable-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Deployment project for your program it is easy to do with the File Types Editor:

1. Select your deployment project
2. Click on the File Types Editor
   button
3. Right click on the "File Types on
   Target Machine"
4. Add File Type
5. Use the Extensions property on your
   new File Type to specify one or more
   file extensions to be associated
   with your program.
6. In the Command property choose
   "Primary output" from your
   application.

Comment: i try, but it don't work. can i get more Details - Maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Remember to set the Command property. I added that to the list.

Answer (score 3):

You can not. You can associate your program with a specific file extension, but you can not FORCE the user to use your program to open a file. Even registration entries are easy to change (open with in the context menu).

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate extension with your program: [Registering the Extension](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SlideShowBuilder.aspx#Registeringtheextension5)