# C# Setting my application as default app

Tags: c#, text, editor, default

I'm a novice programmer and have developed a notepad replacement application for my own needs (with some more features). When I double click a .txt file (or a customizable extension  such as .abc), I want the file to run in my application just like notepad. I read about File Association with programs but I didn't get much of it.

Can someone point me to how I would do this? Just give me a few ideas, I would really like to do this and have an option for my users to set the application as the default text editor. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using click-once deployment (i.e. "publish" in VS for a windows exe), you can specify file associations *there*, and it will do everything for you. I *can't* guarantee that it'll take precedence over notepad, though. For *that* you might need a proper installer...

[MSDN shows how](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892924.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: [how to force that any file of a certain type will open with my program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067545/how-to-force-that-any-file-of-a-certain-type-will-open-with-my-program/4067669#4067669)

Comment: I got it to work with the registerextension() function in a site linked in that page. However there's any another problem. Like I said, I want to load the file in my app so I wrote this in the main function in the program class

if (args.Length == 1)
{
Main x = new Main();
x.Launch(args[0]);
}

Launch is a function in the main form, I added MessageBox.Show(args[0]) in it to see if it worked, it does work but the function launches when I close the app instead of opening it. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
 //Auto set default program to open edi format file
        try
        {
            string currentSavedDefault = "";
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"filetype\shell\open\command"))
            {
                if (key != null)
                {
                    currentSavedDefault = key.GetValue("").ToString();
                }
            }
            String myExecutable = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
            if (currentSavedDefault != myExecutable)
            {
                Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(".type").SetValue("", "filetype", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String);
                Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"filetype\shell\open\command").SetValue("", myExecutable + " %1", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
```