# Setting my program to open its extentions in setup

Tags: c#, .net, installation

When I install my program I want it to open its extentions without OPENWITH dialog ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to force that any file of a certain type will open with my program ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067545/how-to-force-that-any-file-of-a-certain-type-will-open-with-my-program)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mechanism called file association. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-the-current-executable-in-c) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067545/how-to-force-that-any-file-of-a-certain-type-will-open-with-my-program). For additional info use search