# How to implement IDropTarget in an CSharp Application and register it for file types?

Tags: c#, .net, registry, file-type

I'm implementing a small tool in C# which works on files.
Because I'm lazy I want to register my tool on the file types in the registry to be able to simply open all my files from the explorer.
Currently I am using `HCR\MyFile\shell\open\command` to specify the calling command line to my program with `"%1"` for the current file.

This works fine for single files, but oviously not when selecting multiple files.
I found out that my application should implement `IDropTraget` to get multiple files, but I don't know how to do this.

How to my CSharp "application" implement `IDropTraget`?

How to I then register my application in the windows registry for the file types correctly to get it called?

I am relatively new to the whole COM stuff. I "used" it several times now, but I never wrote a COM-class by my own.
Is there an example or tutorial? (I searched, but found nothing, at least I recognized nothing in this direction)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your application uses Windows Forms, any class deriving from Control can set the AllowDrop property to true and handle D&D (almost) automatically.

See here for something similar: [Drag and Drop files from Windows Explorer to Windows Form](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dragdrop.aspx)

Otherwise, you can still reuse Windows forms implementation at a lower level as IDropTarget is defined here: [IDropTaget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.idroptarget.aspx)

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for the answer, but what is missing is how do I then register my application for file types in the registry?

Comment: @3of4 - Here is a link on SO for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-the-current-executable-in-c

Comment: I only find file associations using the normal open verbs there. This is what I am currently doing and what results in the problem I am having (each file will be opened in a separate process). I read somewhere that IDropTarget can be used to get multiple files into one process. But I think I will rephrase my question (after another round in google) and ask it again. Thanks for your help.