# How to associate SDF files (sqlCE) with my C# program?

Tags: c#, winforms

I a made C# program that opens and show sdf files (sqlCE).

How to make it so (on my program installation) that all *.sdf files

in my computer will be opened with my program ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using as your packager?

Comment: ClickOnce provides an easy way to set this up from within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **A Full Example you can use easily: [C# Set File Type Association](http://mel-green.com/2009/04/c-set-file-type-association/)**

You'll need to create a key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT with the name set to your file extension (eg: ".txt"). Set the default value of this key to a unique name for your file type, such as "Acme.TextFile". Then create another key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT with the name set to "Acme.TextFile". Add a subkey called "DefaultIcon" and set the default value of the key to the file containing the icon you wish to use for this file type. Add another sibling called "shell". Under the "shell" key, add a key for each action you wish to have available via the Explorer context menu, setting the default value for each key to the path to your executable followed by a space and "%1" to represent the path to the file selected.

For instance, here's a sample registry file to create an association between .txt files and EmEditor:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt]
@="emeditor.txt"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\emeditor.txt]
@="Text Document"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\emeditor.txt\DefaultIcon]
@="%SystemRoot%\\SysWow64\\imageres.dll,-102"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\emeditor.txt\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\emeditor.txt\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\emeditor.txt\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\EmEditor\\EMEDITOR.EXE\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\emeditor.txt\shell\print]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\emeditor.txt\shell\print\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\EmEditor\\EMEDITOR.EXE\" /p \"%1\""
```

*[Answer From Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-the-current-executable-in-c)*

So you should edit the registry on installation.
Use [Microsoft.Win32 Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.aspx) To edit/add/remove Registry Keys.

Comment: thanks for the help !, but I did not understand - if i need that my program in (d:\OpenSDF.exe) will open all *.sdf files on my computer. what i need to change in this file ?

Comment: @Gali Look at this [Link](http://mel-green.com/2009/04/c-set-file-type-association/).
Then use this code:
``if (!FileAssociation.IsAssociated(".sdf"))
   Associate(".sdf", "ClassID.ProgID", "sdf File", "YourIcon.ico", "D:\OpenSDF.exe");``

Comment: sorry, its work !!!, but how to deal if the .sdf was Associate to different program ?

Comment: and how i can change Associated file to new ?

Comment: Just use
``if (!FileAssociation.IsAssociated(".sdf")) Associate(".sdf", "ClassID.ProgID", "sdf File", "YourIcon.ico", "D:\DifferentProgram.exe");``