# Saving application specific save files C# visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, savefiledialog

I have created an application in C# with visual studio. The application has a Save dialog box which saves to an xml file and a Load dialog box which loads the xml data into the application.

This all works well but what I really want to do is when the application saves the file it creates an application specific file that if the user double clicks it, it will open the application and load the data into it kinda like if you double click a .psd file it will open photoshop and load the file.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Thanks so much,
Airlok

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to associate a file extension to the current executable in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-the-current-executable-in-c)

Comment: Just make sure you do save it with an application specific extension and not .xml. Otherwise you will end up associating all .xml files with your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the file with a custom extension and register it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-the-current-executable-in-c).