# Open specific files with my c# application - like opening .doc files with Word

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, file

You can set *Windows* to open .doc files with Word or another application. How can I create such a c# applications, which can handle, if for excample I open a *.txt* file with that application? So the plan is: There's a *information.kkk* file wich is a text file and there's a number in it. I want my c# application (*Visual Studio 2010*) to receive that number if the file gets opened by it.

Comment: There is an older answer in [SO here][1] that seems to cover your requirements.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-the-current-executable-in-c-sharp

Comment: Agree I was just about to paste that,.,. you beets me!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application This one seems a cleaner approach tho

Comment: where do I get the string of the file in c#? I didn't quite understand it there. so you can set in Windows to open the file with your application, but inside c# - how do you handle the string of the file?

Comment: @weiszam - You would have to write code to read the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open a *ddd.txt* with your application (*the exe file*), then the *string[] Args* will have two items: the program's path itself and the *ddd.txt* path. The following sample code shows you how you put your *ddd.txt* file in a *textBox* on *Form1*. Many thanks everyone for the help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static class Environment
        {
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        string filePath = args[0];
        for (int i = 0; i <= args.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (args[i].EndsWith(".exe") == false)
            {
                textBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(args[i],
                Encoding.Default);
            }
        }
    }
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        string filePath = args[0];
    }


}
public sealed class StartupEventArgs : EventArgs
{

}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Console application use args parameter in Main function. First arg is path to opening file.

For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var filePath = args[0];

        //...
    }
}
```

In WPF application use Application_Startup event:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var filePath = e.Args[0];
    //...
}
```

Or use Enviroment class - anywhere in your .net application:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
string filePath = args[0];
```

Comment: What do I do wrong if I use WindowsFormsApplication? It does not recognise the args part.
![image](http://weisza.uw.hu/fajlok/args.png).

Comment: @weiszam: Use Enviroment class (edited answer) or add parameter "string[] args" to Main method (Program.cs) - static void Main(string[] args). [Example link](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WindowsFormsStartParams.aspx)

Comment: It seems to work perfectly now. I'll paste the code of an excample application below. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();            


// Set filter for file extension and default file extension 

dlg.DefaultExt = ".kkk"; 

dlg.Filter = "KKK documents (.kkk)|*.kkk";
```