# Open custom file with own application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to associate a file extension to the current executable in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-the-current-executable-in-c-sharp)

So, I'm making an application for school (final project).

In this application, I have a `Project`-class. 
This can be saved as a custom file, e.g. Test.**gpr**. 
(.gpr is the extension).

How can I let windows/my application associate the .gpr file with this application, so that if I doubleclick the .gpr file, my application fires and opens the file 
(so launches the OpenProject method - This loads the project).

I am **NOT** asking how to let windows associate a file type with an application, I am asking how to catch this in my code in Visual Studio 2012.

**UPDATE:**
Since my question seems to be not so clear:

> atm, I've done nothing, so I can follow whatever is the best solution. All I want is to doubleclick the .gpr, make sure windows knows to open it with my app, and catch the filepath in my application.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you associate an extension with your application, then the filename is passed as the first parameter (command line) to your main/WinMain function when the user double-clicks a file of that type.

Comment: @Cameron, you mean something like Form(string path-to-.gprfile) as some sort of constructor?

Comment: Windows needs to be able to know to run your application in the first place when you doubleclick the file. And the way to do that is through a file association, which you seem to not want to do. Are you saying your application will already be running and detect the file open attempt by Explorer?

Comment: He means that in your `static void Main(string[] args)`, `args[0]` will be the path to the file.

Comment: @Valentijn: No, sorry (I thought this was a C++ question for some reason). Niko clarified what I meant (thanks @Niko!).

Comment: @itsme86, atm, I've done nothing, so I can follow whatever is the best solution. All I want is to doubleclick the .gpr, make sure windows knows to open it with my app, and catch the filepath in my application.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you open a file with an application, the path to that file is passed as the **first command line argument**.

In C#, this is `args[0]` of your `Main` method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if(args.Length == 1) //make sure an argument is passed
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(args[0]);
        if(file.Exists) //make sure it's actually a file
        {
           //Do whatever
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

---

## WPF

In case your project is an WPF application, in your `App.xaml` add a `Startup` event handler:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             Startup="Application_Startup"> <!--this line added-->
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Your command line arguments will now be in `e.Args` of the `Application_Startup` event handler:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Args.Length == 1) //make sure an argument is passed
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(e.Args[0]);
        if(file.Exists) //make sure it's actually a file
        {
           //Do whatever
        }
    }
}
```