# Make an application to open your own file extension

Tags: java, file

Just like when you click on a .txt file, it opens in notepad I want to make an application in Java that will open my custom file extensions. I found how to do it in C++, but I want it in Java.
When I double click on a certain file, it should open in GUI. I need the code to write this GUI.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: means you want to open your own file extension ?

Comment: You mean you want a GUI to open something? You could use `Swing` framework. And what does your custom file contain?

Comment: Visite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java/6163701#6163701

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows you need to modify the registry like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69826/1178052

To modify the registry in Java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163701/1178052