# How can I establish my windows form application (c#) as the principle application to open a file extension?

Tags: c#, winforms, file

I have a windows form application made in c#, and I want to set a file extension (.txt for example) to open automactily with my application and my icon instead of the NotePad. How can I do it?

Comment: Does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-the-current-executable-in-c-sharp answer your question?

Comment: Yes, Thanks Bart De Boeck

Comment: And how to put a description of the file extension, for example, instead of "ABC file" I want to write "ABC Document" in the description of the extension. How can I do it?